# How to install latest official refinerycms-calendar 2.0.2 in RefineryCMS 2.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms

I have been eating my nails the whole weekend to figure out the right combination of modifications to the official `refinerycms-calendar` in order to make it work with RefineryCMS 2.1.1.

Here are my conclusions and efforts, hoping that someone will drive me to the right direction:

1. Adding just `gem 'refinerycms-calendar', '~>2.0.0'`
   as suggested in the github page is not working out of the box. You need to correct the dependencies on the `.gemspec` file. There are many forks out there created only for this correction.
2. So, I forked the `refinery/refinerycms-calendar` project, corrected the dependencies and used my fork in the `Gemfile`.
3. Backend (BE) works fine: Created an event, went back to FrontEnd (FE), got a "This page is NOT live for viewing"
4. This frontend (FE) inconcistency is corrected to the BE > Pages > Venues page: /calendar/venues is not an existing route and needs to be corrected to /calendar/events. The seeds.rb needs to be corrected for a permanent solution.
5. Go back to FE, now the /calendar/events is blank! I only get the title of the Page as defined on the relative Pages page.
6. A look on the rails server log reveals that there is a :find_page error resulting form the fact that the refinerycms-events.css under the engine's public/stylesheets folder is neither picked up nor referenced correctly inside show.hrml.erb and index.html.erb files. I copied the refinerycms-events.css under vendor/stylesheets and changed the reference to refinerycms-events.css accordingly.
7. Refreshed FE but still there is a blank page both when getting /calendar/events and /calendar/events/#{event}

NOTE: If I "rake routes" I can see that the routes for the FE portion are repeated 3 times. I am not quite sure for this behavior, but when I substituted `"Refinery::Core::Engine.routes.append do".gsub("append","draw")`, I could only see them once.

I have tried many forks around and all of those seem to demonstrate the same behavior.

Can anybody please let me know:

a. If you finally managed to have this (official refinery release) engine fully functional in your projects and if yes which branch was used and with which exact Refinerycms and refinerycms-calendar version combination.

b. If used used a fork rather than the official `refinerycms-calendar` release, then which fork/branch is that.

I hope someone to have that nailed down.

Best regards,

Petros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seems that changing `:body_content_left` and `:body_content_right` with `:body` and `:side_body` respectively inside the Engine's `show` and `index` views, solves the issue of the `/calendar/events` and `/calendar/events/:event` FE pages being blank.

I am still unsure why this is causing such an issue and it is kind of weird nobody to have reported it until now.